# Ansible json output return hello world

Tags: ansible, proxmox, json

newbie on ansible i try to check if a json dict output exist from the proxmox API, but seems like i don't register the output correctly:

here is the yaml : 
https://pastebin.com/XdA5PMNg

and here is the debug : 
https://pastebin.com/qxbsJ8rE

Thanks all

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code. From the code you provided it is unclear to me what your problem is.

Comment: Did you find your solution?  It looks like you haven't indented the 'var' argument for your debug properly.

Comment: yes  i added json.cloudinit.data.["ide2"] thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works now i changed the resgister from `cloudinit.stdout` to `cloudinit` and i use the output like `json.cloudinit.data.["ide2"] is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The output goes to `mystuff.stdout.stdout` which is confusing.

Use `register: mystuff` instead of `register: mystuff.stdout` and you're good.